# External jar finalname

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Is it possible to change the finalname of external jar in the pom file in Maven?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>iText</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I would like to change it so only this specific jar name would be in the camel case. Instead of itext-2.1.7.jar I would like to have iText-2.1.7.jar. How Can I achieve it?

Comment: Firstly, why? Secondly, no.

Comment: Case sensitive update mechanism which thinks that this jar is updated because in old version it was camel case so I need to keep it the same.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use lowercase artifactId.. and apart from that not possible as already mentioned.

Comment: I got no influence on update mechanism and I must ensure that this jar will not be replaced so the only way is to change it. I was thinking about maybe using plugin copy-rename-maven-plugin to rename the jar after its created. Not elegant way but I need to do it somehow.

Comment: Why not change the update mechanism?

Comment: @TheBezwet Rename is done locally on your hard drive but not the artifactId which is the one which is relevant for the name in your repository.

Answer (score -1):

There's no direct way. So as an ugly workaround;

Add a sub module to your project and add this dependency there and package using assembly plugin. Change the sub module's artifact ID as you wish. (Basically this new module will be the wrapper for this dependency). In the runtime, the classes will be available.

You should define this module as the top element of the `<modules>` tag. So that it will be built first. and updated in the `.m2`. That also makes sure that your code will compile just fine any where without referring to the artifact from the maven central.

Again, there's no OOTB way. Hence this.